# Login to Amazon EC2 via ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a question and am stuck at something. I recently created AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance with default settings. I have an Ubuntu machine locally as well and so far I managed to connect successfully to the Ubuntu instace with this command

```
ssh -i /var/www/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

However I want to know if there is a simpler way to login to ssh without passing the private key everytime I login and add its ip to my `~/.ssh/config` so that I could login as easily as `ssh ubuntu@some.ip.number`. By the way I am using AWS free tier package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `~/.ssh/config` with:

```
Host myhost
  IdentityFile /var/www/my-key-pair.pem
  Use ec2-user
  Hostname ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

And the you can login using `ssh myhost`.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh-add -K /var/www/my-key-pair.pem` will permanently add your private key as identity file in `~/.ssh/config`.

Thus, `ssh username@ip_address_of_ec2_instance` works.

To avoid typing username and IP address every time, add to `.ssh/config`:

```
Host my-instance
HostName some.ip.address.here
User username
```

With this config, you can simply do `ssh my-instance` to remote login.

Comment: Thank you the '-K' invoke did not work so removed the '-K' and it worked. but did not see any change in the ~/.ssh/config file.

Comment: -K used to be for adding private key permanently in ~/.ssh/config file. ssh-add adds your key to ssh agent. To do this permanently, add a line "Identityfile /var/www/my-key-pair.pem" to your config.